# Presto Superset query unable to find configuration property of new storage account

Tags: presto, azure-hdinsight, apache-superset, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

We have an Azure HDInsight cluster setup that runs Presto and Superset app connecting to it. We recently onboarded a new storage account to the cluster by updating `core-site.xml`, which allows us to create an external table from the Hive View.

We are able to query the external table from the new storage account in the Hive View without issue.

In the Superset app, we are able to locate the external table and see the table schema without issue.

But when trying to query the external table over the Superset app via Presto, it says `presto error: Configuration property storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net not found`

Anyone know what is missing from our setup? Any advice is appreciated.

[core-site.xml setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qegMS.png)

[external table query successful in Hive View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KZTj.png)

[Presto not able to query the same table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mMTh.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. We simply need to restart the Presto.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.